# Multiclass classification imbalance

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data

I have 5 different labels, with the followings percentages of frequency:

```
 '0': 23.21%
 '1': 17.64%
 '2': 29.64%
 '3': 16.96%
 '4': 12.57%
```

How can I evaluate if this can badly affect my predictions? I have ~1800 records with 28 features each.

I thought about using cross-validation with confusion matrix, but I'm pretty unsure about that

Comment: you can use class_weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a performance measure that takes into account the number of samples for each label, such as the [micro- or weighted-averaged F1 score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html).